# Convert NSString to Integer in objective - c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays

I have an array that stores each digit of a phone number as a string. I then pass the phone number digit string as an argument for `objectAtIndex`: method of `NSArray` like this: `[myArray objectAtIndex: [myString intValue]];` The compiler says I need to cast the String but I am already doing that. What is wrong?

#### Update:

Here's my actual line of code:

```
NSMutableArray *tmp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[charHolder objectAtIndex:[[phoneNumDigits objectAtIndex:i]intValue]]];
```

This is where the error is, `phoneNumDigits` is an array of each digit of the phone number, `charHolder` is the array holding the array of letters associated with each digit.

Comment: What is the actual value of `myString`?

Comment: some code will help us to help you and please put source code parts into 'code' tags

Comment: Is that your *actual* code, or is that your retyping of your code? If you could post a snippet here, that should help greatly.

Comment: You need to show where you initialize `myString`

Comment: thats not my actual code, I'll post it in a second

Comment: And not to be a pain, but what is the actual error?

Comment: @GeeGoldz, it would be great for you next time you ask a question if you accept an answer here.

Answer (score 6):

Your question is a little confusing to me. Here is how I understand what you want to do:

You have an `NSArray` named `phoneNumDigits`. This array contains a few `NSString` objects. Each string is something like `@"1"` or `@"4"` and represents a single digit of a phone number.

Now you want to convert each of those digit strings to `int` or `NSInteger` and want to store these integers in another array.

If I understood you correctly, here is my answer:

You cannot exactly do what you want, because you can't put a simple data type like an `int` or a `float` into an `NSArray`.

That's why there is the wrapper class `NSNumber`. You can package a simple `int` in an `NSNumber` and store this `NSNumber` in an `NSArray`.

So to get your string digits from the `phoneNumDigits` into the `tmp` array you could use this code:

```
for (NSString *digitAsString in phoneNumDigits)
{
    NSNumber *digitAsNumber = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[digitAsString intValue]];
    [tmp addObject:digitAsNumber];
}
```

To get the `int`s out of the tmp-`NSArray` you would use

```
int digit = [[tmp objectAtIndex:idx] intValue];
```

I hope this helps, but I'm not sure I understand what you want to do here. I could be completely missing the point. Maybe you could share some more code.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableArray *tmp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[charHolder objectAtIndex:[[phoneNumDigits objectAtIndex:i]intValue]]];
```

`objectAtIndex` returns a generic object (`id`). It has no idea that the object in the array is a string as it could be anything. So you need to cast it. Or to increase readabilty, create variables for them. Eg:

```
int phoneNumberDigit = [phoneNumDigits objectAtIndex:i];
NSArray *chars = [charHolder objectAtIndex:phoneNumberDigit];
NSMutableArray *tmp = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:chars];
```